# ng-repeat and ng-switch doesn't work on same element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

JS

```
$scope.mode = "test"
$scope.array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

HTML

```
<div ng-switch on="mode">
    <div ng-repeat="item in array" ng-switch-when="test">
        Test {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I do this the above, the output I get is

```
Test Test Test
```

It can't seem to access item. If I remove the ng-switch-when then it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because `ng-switch` creates a child scope and same applies for ng-repeat. ng-repeat runs at priority **[1000](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)** and `ng-switch` at **[800](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)**. So the child scope created by `ng-repeat` on each of the repeated div elements gets overwritten by `ng-switch`, so the `ng-repeat` assigned child scope on the element is gone ultimately. A possibly way could be to wrap your ng-switch outside ng-repeat since you anyways do not want to evaluate the ng-switch expression for every repeated element. This is with the 1.2 version.

Now from 1.3.x version of angular the priority of ng-switch has been revise to **[1200](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)** and ng-repeat remains at **1000**, so ng-repeated scope will prevail, since it is of lower priority now and it will work in that case.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLtmZ8?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer. Wish there was a debugger to use that can help me visualize the scopes in case I run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @allenylzhou Upgrade to latest version of angular and you should be good.