# How to use ng-switch on ng-repeat-start

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNLJWV which allows me to repeat elements without a parent node and select the one I want. My question is it possible to replace the `ng-if` with `ng-switch` and achieve the same result? I tried but it broke the `ng-repeat-end`.

Below is the code embedded:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-if="item.type == 'text'">
      I'm a paragraph
    </p>
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'video'">
      I'm a video
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.type == 'iframe'">
      I'm an iframe
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {
      type: "text"
    },
    {
      type: "video"
    },
    {
      type: "iframe"
    }
  ]
})
```

### EDIT

So after playing with it more, i think this is the error I'm getting: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngSwitch&p1=ngSwitchWhen

So i guess the question would be more, "is it possible to have ng-switch without parent like ng-repeat-start?"

Comment: So is your question now about having an ng-switch without a ng-repeat-start parent? Because if so, then yes it is possible.

Comment: @VladBardalez I need my `ng-switch` to be on the same level as `ng-repeat-start`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat and ng-switch doesn't work on same element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675742/ng-repeat-and-ng-switch-doesnt-work-on-same-element)